# magento ER diagrams

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I have wasted a lot of time to find the ER diagrams of magento, but unable to find.How can I get the complete ER diagram of magento 1.9.x version so that i can under whole database flow quickly.

Comment: There is no official document for it. you can check this http://www.magereverse.com

Answer (score 2):

ER diagram for 1.9.x is not available,however you can check bellow link to get some idea.

[Database Diagram](https://inchoo.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/MAGENTO_v1.3.2.4-Database_Diagram.pdf)